# Getting invalid response on data of api using dio in flutter

Tags: flutter, dio

i want to pass username and token from login screen to dashboard, i saved it using sharedpreference and call it to dashboard, i'm getting values too. but when i pass them to my api, using dio and print it's response.data it gives me Error wherease it's statuscode is 200. kindly help me with to fix this issue.

here is my code

```
 var localhostUrl="http://10.0.2.2:8000/TimeIn";

_userDetails() async{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
          getname=myPrefs.getString('name');
          getdesignation=myPrefs.getString('designation');
          getTimeInStatus=myPrefs.getBool('timeInStatus');
          getaccesstoken=myPrefs.getString('accesstoken');
        }); 
  }

  calltimeInApi() async {

      Dio dio=new Dio(
        BaseOptions(
        connectTimeout: 30000,
        baseUrl: localhostUrl,
        responseType: ResponseType.json,
        contentType: ContentType.json.toString(),
    ));
    var data={
      'username':getname
    };
    dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer ${getaccesstoken}";  
    await dio.post(localhostUrl,data: data).then((onResponse)  async {
        print(onResponse.headers);
        print(onResponse.statusCode);
        print(onResponse.data);
    ;
    });}
```

here is the output

```
I/flutter (14995): 1
I/flutter (14995): x-powered-by: Express
I/flutter (14995): connection: keep-alive
I/flutter (14995): keep-alive: timeout=5
I/flutter (14995): date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 18:34:53 GMT
I/flutter (14995): content-length: 7
I/flutter (14995): etag: W/"7-Vuu5vA8hV5HSudFEr8bWQajjaE0"
I/flutter (14995): content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
I/flutter (14995): 200  //statuscode
I/flutter (14995): Error  //data
```

-----------**Updated**

i have tried all possible answers which i got from internet but no one resolves my problem

```
  calltimeInApi() async {

      Dio dio=new Dio(
        BaseOptions(
        connectTimeout: 30000,
        baseUrl: localhostUrlTimeIn,
        headers: {"Accept":"application/json"}
        //contentType: ContentType.json.toString(),
    ));
    var data={
      "username":getname
    };
    dio.options.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer ${getaccesstoken}";
    await dio.post(localhostUrlTimeIn,data: json.encode(data)).then((onResponse)  async {
        print(onResponse.headers);
        if (onResponse.statusCode == 200) {
         print(json.decode(onResponse.data));
        } else {
          print(onResponse.statusCode);
        }
        //print(onResponse.statusCode);
        //print(json.decode(onResponse.data));
    // print(response.statusCode);
    // print(response.headers);
    // print(response.statusMessage);
    // print(response.data);
    });}
```

here are logs of the above updated code

```
I/flutter (14995): 1
I/flutter (14995): x-powered-by: Express
I/flutter (14995): connection: keep-alive
I/flutter (14995): keep-alive: timeout=5
I/flutter (14995): date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 19:20:41 GMT
I/flutter (14995): content-length: 7
I/flutter (14995): etag: W/"7-Vuu5vA8hV5HSudFEr8bWQajjaE0"
I/flutter (14995): content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
E/flutter (14995): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (14995): Error
E/flutter (14995): ^
E/flutter (14995):
```

**-----------------------------------UPDATED-----------------------------**
i try to pass token in data, my api is working properly it response successfully according to my requirement but it's still giving me Error on response.data.

here is my update code

```
calltimeInApi() async {

    Dio dio=new Dio();
    var data={
      'username': getname,
      'token': getaccesstoken
    };
    await dio
    .post(localhostUrlTimeIn,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse)  async {
        print(onResponse.data);
        print(onResponse.headers);
        print(onResponse.statusCode);
      }).catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
        //showAlertDialog(context);
    });

    
  }
```

please help if anyone know how to fix it

Comment: data from dio is always of type dynamic , remove this ` responseType: ResponseType.json,` . Whatever dat you get back, do decode that

Comment: print(json.decode(onResponse.data)); i print this and it gives me ``` Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (14995): Error
E/flutter (14995): ^  ```

Answer (score 0):

//editing your dio

```
      Dio createDio() {
         //configure dio
        
          Dio dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
            connectTimeout: 50000,
            receiveTimeout: 50000,
            baseUrl: ApiPaths.BASE_URL,
          ));
         ;
        //add interceptors 
        dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
          onRequest: (Options options, handler) async {
            print('send request：path:${options.path}，baseURL:${options.baseUrl}');
    //==============fetch your token and parse it here as csrfToken============
            if (csrfToken == null) {
              print('no token，request token firstly...');
              //lock the dio.
              dio.lock();
              //token null , try getting new token
                handler.next(options);
              }).catchError((error, stackTrace) {
                handler.reject(error, true);
              }) .whenComplete(() => dio.unlock()); // unlock the dio
            } else {
//here add your token 
          options.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer $csrfToken";
             
              handler.next(options);
            }
          }
        ));
        
          (dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
              (HttpClient client) {
            client.badCertificateCallback =
                (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
              final isValidHost = host == ApiPaths.BASE_URL;
              return true;
            };
            
            return client;
          };
          return dio;
        }
        
        var dioHelper = createDio();
```

Edit your dio.post to match this . You nolonger need to create dio again. Anywhere you need to access dio use `dioHelper`

```
Response response= await dioHelper.post(localhostUrlTimeIn,data: json.encode(data));

print(response.statusCode)
print(response.data)
//you decode when parsing to an object model
```

Comment: Can u please check am i passing token in correct way?